# A disk read error occurred on Windows after installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: grub2, 12.10

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10, and I had Windows 7 on my machine. Now Windows is giving me

> A disk read error occurred

I can't use my Windows anymore. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restored MBR using boot-repair.
Thanks all.

Comment: can you please share more info on how to access it and recover my windows ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you still boot to "Ubuntu"?

If so, start Ubuntu and navigate to [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted). Start it and use the program to check your Windows partition. Often GParted can fix these errors.

Good luck, BTW. You can also use GParted from a [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD)/USB.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same thing. I haven't found the fix yet but I will try the suggestion.
However I could boot Windows by using the built in boot menu of my Packard Bell (F12) and choosing the Windows partition directly.